# Realizar busquedas de app en YARN Hadoop, via api rest

Tags: python, yarn, hadoop

He estado averiguando realizar una busqueda de apps en YARN de HADOOP via su api en python, por columna `name`; sin embarno aún no he logrado, solo encontré por `application_id`, ejem: `GET http://rm-http-address:port/ws/v1/cluster/apps/application_1476912658570_0002`, en principio no sé que app_id podria tener mi fuente, por ello si o sí debo buscar por nombre.

Algo asi me imagino que seria mi búsqueda: `/ws/v1/cluster/apps/?name=xxxx`, aunque cuando pongo asi me devulve todos los resultados y lo que quiero es solo de ese app por su nombre. Hay alguna forma de lograr esto?

hice este avance en Python, aunque me devuelve todos los resultados en base a params `states`

```
import requests

HOST_BASE = "111.22.33.22"
PORT_BASE = "8088"
def get_url_base() -> str:

    """
    Construye y retorna la URL base para las consultas al cluster.
    La URL se construye a partir de constantes globales para el HOST_BASE y el PORT_BASE
    """
    url_base = f"http://{HOST_BASE}:{PORT_BASE}/ws/v1/cluster"
    return url_base


def get_running_apps(name=None):
    print("URL_BASE:", get_url_base())
    resource = "/apps"
    params = {"states": ["RUNNING", "ACCEPTED"]}
    
    # Agregar el parámetro "name" si se proporciona


    headers = {"accept": "application/json"}

    r = requests.get(
        get_url_base() + resource, params=params, headers=headers, timeout=300
    )
    data = r.json()

    try:
        return data["apps"]["app"]
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"error: {e}")
        return []

# Ejemplo de uso:
# Obtener aplicaciones en ejecución con un nombre específico
running_apps = get_running_apps()

if running_apps:
    for app in running_apps:
        print(f"ID: {app[   'id']}, Name: {app['name']}")
else:
    print(f"No se encontraron aplicaciones con el nombre: {desired_name}")
print("CANTIDAD:", len(running_apps))
```

En esta script quisiera pasar el nombre de la fuente: `name`, que deberia devolverme un solo resultado.

he visto otros apis rest como: `/ws/v1/cluster/appstatistics?states=accepted`, que sí te devuelve un solo registro.

Visualmente si me encuentra correctamente, este mismo comportamamiento deseo lograr via api:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias